# Compute expectation of Brownian motion integral $\int_0^t E[\cos(B_u)|F_s] du$

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, brownian-motion, expected-value

I'm stuck with the computation of $$\int_0^t E[\cos(B_u)|F_s] du$$

where $F_s$ is the natural filtration and $0<s<t$.

I tried to separate the cases when $u \in [0,s]$ and $u \in[s,t]$, but I'm not sure how to go on.

How should I move?

---

**Edit**

Now I write $$\int_0^t E[\cos(B_u)|F_s]du = \int_0^t E[\cos(B_u) \mathcal{1}_{[0,s]} + \cos(B_u) \mathcal{1}_{[s,t]}|F_s]du= \\
\int_0^s E[\cos(B_u)]du + \int_s^t E[\cos(B_u)|F_s]du$$

Now $E[\cos(B_u)|F_s] = E[\cos(B_u - B_s + B_s)|F_s] =  E[\cos(B_u - B_s) \cos(B_s) - \sin(B_s) \sin(B_u - B_s)|F_s] = \cos(B_s) E[\cos(B_u - B_s)]$

The expectation with the sine is $0$ since $B_u - B_s$ is normally distributed and since the integrand function $\sin(x) \exp(\ldots)$ is odd on a symmetric interval.

Now, $E[\cos(B_u - B_s)] = e^{-\frac{u-s}{2}}$, by looking at the characteristic function.

Therefore

$$\int_s^t E[\cos(B_u)|F_s]du = \int_s^t \cos(B_s) e^{-\frac{u-s}{2}} du = \cos(B_s) \int_s^t e^{-\frac{u-s}{2}} du = \cos(B_s) (2-2 e^{\frac{s-t}{2}})$$

Summing up everything I get:

$$ \int_0^t E[\cos(B_u)|F_s] du = \int_0^s \cos(B_u)du + \cos(B_s) (2-2 e^{\frac{s-t}{2}})$$

Comment: Here's a few ideas to get you started:
In the case $u \in [s,t]$ consider $E[\cos((B_u-B_s)+B_s)]$ and use double angle formulae. In order to work out $E[\cos(B_u-B_s)]$ use $B_u-B_s \sim N(0,u-s)$ and $\cos(x) = \frac{e^{ix}+e^{-ix}}{2}$ in the gaussian integral.

Comment: Thanks @fGDu94 I edited my answer, could you please tel me if it's okay now? I follow your suggestion to start the proof

Answer (score 1):

Note

$$\int_0^t E[\cos B_u|F_s] du=\int_0^s \cos B_u du+\int_s^t E[\cos B_u|F_s] du\tag 1$$

where the  first integral is deterministic and known given the filtration $F_s$. To calculate the second integral, apply Ito's law to $\cos B_t$

$$d(\cos B_t) = -\sin B_tdB_t - \frac12  \cos B_t dt$$

Integrate over $(s,t)$ to get

$$\cos B_t -\cos B_s = -\int_s^t \sin B_tdB_t - \frac12 \int_s^t \cos B_u du$$

Therefore,

$$\int_s^t E[\cos B_u|F_s]du = 2\cos B_s - 2E[\cos B_t| F_s]$$

where the expectation on the RHS can be computed with the normal density function,

$$E[\cos B_t| F_s] = \frac1{\sqrt{2\pi (t-s)}}\int_{-\infty}^{-\infty}\cos x \>e^{-\frac{(x- B_s)^2}{2(t-s)}} = \cos B_se^{-\frac {t-s}2}$$

Thus, plug the result into (1) to obtain

$$\int_0^t E[\cos B_u|F_s] du = \int_0^s \cos B_u du + 2\cos B_s (1-{e^{-\frac {t-s}2}})$$

Comment: I forgot to mention that I can't use Ito's law

Comment: I follow your first part and edited my answer @Quanto. Could you tell me if it's okay now?

Comment: could you please give a check?

Comment: @Vefhug - The edited post looks fine